# Catch a RTK Query fulfilled action in redux toolkit middleware

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to fire some side-effects after one of my RTKQ queries completes. I decided the best way would be to do it inside a middleware but I'm not sure what is the correct way to get catch this action.

After some debugging, I end up with something like below but it looks a bit hackish to me.

```js
const recreateTransferOnAppStartMiddleware: Middleware<unknown, RootState> = 
  storeApi => next => action => {
    const isFulfilledAction = action.type === `api/executeQuery/fulfilled`;
    const isGetUserAction = action.meta
      && action.meta.arg
      && action.meta.arg.endpointName === `getUser`;

    if (isFulfilledAction && isGetUserAction)
      recreateTransfers(storeApi);

    return next(action);
};
```

My biggest problem with this code is that it is string based when checking for `endpointName` and `action.type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found it is possible to access an endpoint matcher directly:

```
const recreateTransferOnAppStartMiddleware: Middleware<unknown, RootState> = storeApi => next => action => {
    const isGetUserFulfilled = userApiSlice.endpoints.getUser.matchFulfilled(action);

    if (isGetUserFulfilled)
        recreateTransfers(storeApi);

    return next(action);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint's [`onQueryStarted`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) property might be of better use for you here. You can run some additional logic when the query starts, or when it settles, i.e. when it completes.

Here's an example:

```js
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: ....,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUser: build.query<...., ....>({
      query: ....,
      async onQueryStarted(_, { queryFulfilled }) {
        // `onStart` side-effect
        // anything you want to run when the query starts

        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
          // `onSuccess` side-effect
          // anything you want to run when the query succeeds
        } catch (err) {
          // `onError` side-effect
          // anything you want to run when the query fails
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative, that would work indeed, but I don't feel my logic fits well into my API slice. I learned how to access an API endpoint matchers directly and that was what I needed (see my answer).

Comment: @Rychu Fair enough, happy to help either way. Cheers and good luck!